# Socket connect() on iOS blocks for more than 30 seconds

Tags: ios, sockets, networking

I have no clue what is causing this, but using a socket on iOS and calling connect() makes the app hang for 30s to 1 minute or more. And when it finally returns, half of the time the connection failed, even if the server is perfectly working.

I am using low level sockets, since I am avoid having objective C code at all.
What could cause this?

Comment: This is normal behaviour. The `connect()` system call does several internal retries for a total of about a minute before giving a `connection timeout` error. You get this when there is a network connectivity problem.

Comment: Upvoted pointless futile unexplained downvote.

Answer (score 1):

While this behavior is normal, you can set your socket to nonblocking before connecting, and you will be able to do other things while waiting for it.

Use select to see if it's writeable and when that returns true, the connect has completed (one way or another).

Details about how to detect if the connection was successful or not is [here](http://cr.yp.to/docs/connect.html)